# "Forcing unknown" values on output in tests

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to write register file in VHDL. Firstly I'm define storing element for N bits. Secondly implement register file, with WA(write address), RA(read address), WDR/RDP (write/read data port) and other things. After that generate testbench for regfile, but in test getting "X", when taken any data by RA address. How I can fix this? Maybe something wrong in implentation of my regfile?

[image: waveform]

a) Store element for data

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity REGn is 
    generic(INITREG: std_logic_vector:="1001");
    port(Din : in std_logic_vector(INITREG'range);
         EN  : in std_logic;    
         INIT: in std_logic;
         CLK : in std_logic;
         OE  : in std_logic;
         Dout: out std_logic_vector(INITREG'range));
end REGn;

architecture beh_regn of REGn is
    signal reg: std_logic_vector(INITREG'range);    
    constant ALLZ: std_logic_vector(INITREG'range):=(others => 'Z');
begin
    Main: process(Din, EN, INIT, CLK)
    begin                              
        if INIT = '1' then
            reg <= INITREG;
        elsif EN = '1' then
            if rising_edge(CLK) then
                reg <= Din;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    Dout <= reg when OE='0' else ALLZ;
end beh_regn;
```

b) Register file

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity REGFile is
    generic(INITREG: std_logic_vector:="0000";
            a      : integer:=2);
    port(INIT:  in std_logic;
         WDP :  in std_logic_vector(INITREG'range);
         WA  :  in std_logic_vector(a-1 downto 0);
         RA  :  in std_logic_vector(a-1 downto 0);
         WE  :  in std_logic;
         RDP : out std_logic_vector(INITREG'range));
end REGFile;

architecture beh_regfile of REGFile is
    component REGn is
        generic(INITREG: std_logic_vector:="1001");
        port(Din:  in std_logic_vector(INITREG'range);
            EN  :  in std_logic;                   
            INIT:  in std_logic;
            CLK :  in std_logic;
            OE  :  in std_logic;
            Dout: out std_logic_vector(INITREG'range));
    end component;    
    signal wen: std_logic_vector(2**a-1 downto 0);
    signal ren: std_logic_vector(2**a-1 downto 0);
    signal readd: std_logic_vector(INITREG'range);
begin                    
    -- Write decoder
    WAD: process(WA)
    begin
        for i in 0 to 2**a-1 loop   
            if i = CONV_INTEGER(WA) then
                wen(i) <= '1';
            else
                wen(i) <= '0';
            end if;
        end loop;
    end process;               

    -- Read decoder
    RAD: process(RA)
    begin       
        for i in 0 to 2**a-1 loop
            if i = CONV_INTEGER(RA) then
                ren(i) <= '1';
            else
                ren(i) <= '0';
            end if;
        end loop;
    end process;

REGi: for i in 2**a-1 downto 0 generate
    REGi: REGn generic map (INITREG)
               port map (WDP, wen(i), INIT, WE, ren(i), readd);
end generate;

RDP <= readd;
end beh_regfile;
```

c) Testbench for register file

```
library ieee;       
library std;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use std.textio.all;

    -- Add your library and packages declaration here ...

entity regfile_tb is
    -- Generic declarations of the tested unit
        generic(
        INITREG : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR := "0000";
        a : INTEGER := 2 );
end regfile_tb;

architecture TB_ARCHITECTURE of regfile_tb is
    -- Component declaration of the tested unit
    component regfile
        generic(
        INITREG : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR := "0000";
              a : INTEGER := 2 );
    port(
        INIT : in STD_LOGIC;
        WDP : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(INITREG'range);
        WA : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(a-1 downto 0);
        RA : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(a-1 downto 0);
        WE : in STD_LOGIC;
        RDP : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(INITREG'range) );
    end component;

    -- Stimulus signals - signals mapped to the input and inout ports of tested entity
    signal INIT : STD_LOGIC;
    signal WDP  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(INITREG'range);
    signal WA   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(a-1 downto 0);
    signal RA   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(a-1 downto 0);
    signal WE   : STD_LOGIC;
    -- Observed signals - signals mapped to the output ports of tested entity
    signal RDP : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(INITREG'range);

    -- Add your code here ...               
    type TEST_REC is record          
           INIT : STD_LOGIC;
            WDP : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(INITREG'range);
            WA  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(a-1 downto 0);
            RA  : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(a-1 downto 0);    
            WE  : STD_LOGIC;
    end record;

    type TEST_ARRAY is array(positive range <>) of TEST_REC;
    constant PATTERN : test_array:= (        
        -- initialize
        (INIT=>'1', WDP=>"0000", WA=>"00", RA=>"00", WE=>'0'),
        (INIT=>'1', WDP=>"0000", WA=>"01", RA=>"01", WE=>'0'),
        (INIT=>'1', WDP=>"0000", WA=>"10", RA=>"10", WE=>'0'),
        (INIT=>'1', WDP=>"0000", WA=>"11", RA=>"11", WE=>'0'),
        --- test vectors      
        (INIT=>'0', WDP=>"1000", WA=>"00", RA=>"00", WE=>'1'),
        (INIT=>'0', WDP=>"1000", WA=>"00", RA=>"00", WE=>'0')
    );

begin

    -- Unit Under Test port map
    UUT : regfile
        generic map (
            INITREG => INITREG,
            a => a
        )

        port map (
            INIT => INIT,
            WDP  => WDP,
            WA   => WA,
            RA   => RA,
            WE   => WE,
            RDP  => RDP
        );

    -- Add your stimulus here ...     
    process
        variable VECTOR: TEST_REC;
    begin
        for i in PATTERN'range loop
            VECTOR:= PATTERN(i);     
            INIT  <= VECTOR.INIT;
            WDP   <= VECTOR.WDP;
            WA    <= VECTOR.WA;
            RA    <= VECTOR.RA;    
            WE    <= VECTOR.WE;
            wait for 100 ns;
        end loop;
    end process;          

    process
        variable my_line: line;
    begin                         
        wait for 5ns;
        write(my_line,"WDP=");
        write(my_line,WDP);  
        write(my_line," INIT=");
        write(my_line,INIT);
        write(my_line," WA=");
        write(my_line,WA);
        write(my_line," RA=");
        write(my_line,RA);       
        write(my_line," RDP=");
        write(my_line,RDP);
        writeline(output,my_line);   
        wait for 96ns;
    end process;


end TB_ARCHITECTURE;

configuration TESTBENCH_FOR_regfile of regfile_tb is
    for TB_ARCHITECTURE
        for UUT : regfile
            use entity work.regfile(beh_regfile);
        end for;
    end for;
end TESTBENCH_FOR_regfile;
```

Comment: Drill down into your code to see which signal is driving RDP with some unknown value on bit 0.  Add more signals to your waveform at the lower levels.

Comment: Why are you wiring up WE to your Clk signal?  I would think that Clk should get its own dedicated Clk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output enables aren't correct:

[image: regfile_tb_ghw.png]
*(image linked to full size image)*

Notice three are low at the same time for all four Regn instances and they cause a conflict for the bit of Readd that's different.

In architecture beh_regn of Regn:

```
Dout <= reg when OE='0' else ALLZ;
```

With three output enables '0', a conflict between a '1' and '0' resolves to 'X' (see package std_logic_1164, the body, resolution_table).

You have the assignments to ren(i) inverted, should be:

```
-- Read decoder
RAD: process(RA)
begin       
    for i in 0 to 2**a-1 loop
        if i = CONV_INTEGER(RA) then
            ren(i) <= '0';  -- was '1'
        else
            ren(i) <= '1';  -- was '0'
        end if;
    end loop;
end process;
```

No guarantee this is all that is wrong, but answers ***"... in test getting "X", when taken any data by RA address. How I can fix this? Maybe something wrong in implentation of my regfile?"***

(Invert the assignments to ren(i), yes there is something wrong in REGFile).

Also note despite your VHDL tool allowing it you are required to have white space between a numerical literal and a following identifier (e.g. `96ns` in your test bench).  That won't change in the next revision of the standard.